# PHP/ACCESS/MYSQL Get the auto increment value and adding it to another column with a text behind it

Tags: php, html, sql, ms-access

I don't know how to explain it therefore I don't know how to search for it. I have this insert to in php which looks like this:

```php
$sqlfatura="INSERT INTO faturas_online (cod_fatura,email,totalapagar,data) VALUES ('FO+num_fatura','$login_cookie','$total','$data')";
```

I have an auto-increment field in my database which is receipt_number and I want it to be on receipt_code with FO before it so I can differentiate it from store receipts, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you looking for `last_insert_id()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff maybe i do hahaha im gonna look into it

Comment: With what i found i dont understand it

Comment: @GordonLinoff i just dont understand how to use it in my situation

Comment: And btw i am using commands like odbc_exec and that , not mysql

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want $sqlfatura="INSERT INTO faturas_online (cod_fatura,email,totalapagar,data) VALUES ('FO.$num_fatura','$login_cookie','$total','$data')";

Comment: Thank you for your help but this does not work my friend

Comment: It gives me a undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell us what method you're using for mysql; the answer is different with a pdo vs msqli. You have to read the insert_id after a successful insert. With a pdo you'd do

```
     $pdo = new PDO(mysql...)
     if ($pdo->query("INSERT ..."))
        $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Where $id is the auto_increment key. You can of course not use an autoincrement variable and create the receipt number yourself.

Comment: I am not using any method i would know about , im using all odbc commands